# A specific file is repeatedly hanging Ubuntu 18 during transfer

Tags: nautilus, video, ffmpeg, rsync, filemanager

The file is an .MTS format video stream file. And I'm trying to transfer it between 2 connected external drives. (one an internal in an enclosure)

The problem first became apparent when I noticed that `rsync` repeatedly hangs on the file when trying to transfer it. Not only that, but after hanging, the read-from drive (and sometimes even the entire `/media/MY_USER` folder) is no longer accessible through the GUI or the command line, and I have to hard reboot the system to fix the problem. (Hard reboot because I can't manage to kill the transfer process even with `sudo kill -9 PROCESS_ID` -- it just adds a `<defunct>` to the end of it in the process list -- and shutting down / restarting through normal methods hangs the system on the Ubuntu loading screen before shutdown)

So I tried transferring it with `cp` and also a basic drag and drop in the `nautilus` GUI, but same problem.

Finally I tried re-encoding the file with `ffmpeg` to see if it was some kind of issue in the file's encoding, but ffmpeg hangs on frame 52320.

```
frame=52320 fps=181 q=31.0 size=  358400kB time=00:29:05.64 bitrate=1681.9kbits/
s speed=6.03x
```

Also, strangely VLC doesn't seem to have any problem playing the video...

Any ideas as to why this might be happening?

Comment: UPDATE: Just realized I don't have to restart the system if I do `sudo kill -9` on all `nautilus` processes.

Comment: `<defunct>` usually means that the process's Parent has not done a one of the `wait(2)` system calls, and hasn't colledted the Process's exit status. See `man 2 wait`.

Comment: Ok, do you have any idea why a single, specific file could be causing all of the file transfer and encoding programs that attempt to read or modify it to hang indefinitely though? It's not something I've ever seen before, and I can't find any info on it on the web...

Comment: AskUbuntu is NOT a conversation site. If you have a second question, ask a second question, Questions and answers in the comments are hidden from the AskUbntu search engine, and therefore, don't help future users,